# "Diagonal" embedding of the selfproduct of a conic into $\mathbb P^3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The selfproduct $X\times X$ of a conic $X\subseteq\mathbb P^2$ over a field $k$ should embed into $\mathbb P^3$. The Segre embedding of the selfproduct of a line $\mathbb P^1$ embeds as the surface $\{(x:y:z:w):xw-yz=0\}\subseteq\mathbb P^3$.

I am a bit ashamed but I can't see a simple canonical way of doing this. It is on page 54 of [this](https://www.math.ias.edu/vladimir/sites/math.ias.edu.vladimir/files/s5.pdf) paper that this is stated, the embedding is called "diagonal", without detail. If you take an isomorphism to $\mathbb P^1$, over an extension of $k$ if necessary, then you can compose with the Segre embedding, but this is not canonical, nor "diagonal" I think.

Take $\{x^2+y^2+z^2=0\}\subseteq\mathbb P^2$, an imaginary circle over $\mathbb Q$, what is that embedding?

EDIT: I corrected the title, which mislead by mentioning embedding the conic $X$ itself, rather than $X\times X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can do the following. Consider the diagonal $\Delta_X \subset X \times X$ and the associated line bundle 
$$
L = \mathcal{O}_{X \times X}(\Delta_X).
$$
Over $\bar{k}$ one has $X \times X \cong \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$, and $L \cong \mathcal{O}(1,1)$. Therefore, the morphism defined by $L$ is a morphism
$$
X \times X \to \mathbb{P}^3.
$$
If you restrict it to the diagonal $X = \Delta_X$, you obtain the embedding of the original conic.

Comment: (Corrected comment) Sorry Sasha, I want to embed $X\times X$, not $X$. Could you make explicit the embedding for $X=\mathbb P^1$ and $X=\{x^2+y^2+z^2\}\subseteq\mathbb P^2$, give an equation for the image of $X\times X$? I have to think about it. Also, what exactly is $\mathcal{O}(1,1)$, is it very ample? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I understand better. $Pic(P^1\times P^1)$ is ZxZ and O(1,1) is (1,1) in there, corresponding to the sum of degree 1 Weil divisors, 1 line for each factor. What you use then is just the isomorphism $X\cong P^1$ over $\bar k$ and the Segre embedding, there is no diagonal involved in embedding $X\times X$ in $\mathbb P^3$. I think Voevodsky must be using the diagonal if he mentions it. There must be something else to understand.

Comment: Well or maybe you can call it "diagonal" rather than "Segre", because it is given by the very ample line bundle corresponding to the diagonal as a Weil divisor on $\mathbb P^1\times\mathbb P^1$ and $X\times X$. Yes, I think that justifies Voevodsky's use of the term. Is it what you meant from the beginning? If so I am sorry I was so slow to get it. Thanks alot in any case.

Comment: I am not sure about the meaning of "diagonal" for Voevodsky, but I guess that embedding given by the line bundle associated with the diagonal divisor can be called "diagonal".

Comment: Just to make sure:$L = \mathcal{O}_{X \times X}(\Delta_X)$ yields an embedding $X\times X\rightarrow\mathbb P^3$ over any field $k$, regardless of the isomorphism $X\cong\mathbb P^1$, right? Thanks again.